# How to get all rows from table using T-SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

When executing this query I don't get rows with null in the `EXT_NO` column

```
SELECT * 
FROM KM_USER_MAST 
WHERE EXT_NO = DBO.KM_GET_SRCH_PARAM(NULL, EXT_NO)
```

My intention is to get all the rows including null when the first param is null.

And this is the code of the procedure.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[KM_GET_SRCH_PARAM](
   @param VARCHAR(8000)
   , @whereParam VARCHAR(8000) )
returns varchar(8000)
as
begin
    declare @returnValue varchar(8000);

    IF @param IS NULL OR @param = ''
       SET @returnValue = ISNULL(@whereParam,'');
    ELSE
       SET @returnValue = @param;

    return @returnValue
end
```

Any method to get all rows???

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the function? Applying a function on a table column prevents the server from using indexes. There is probably a better way to do whatever you are trying to do here

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what your function is trying to achieve?

if you want to retrieve all rows with null value for EXT_NO :

```
SELECT * 
FROM KM_USER_MAST 
WHERE EXT_NO IS NULL
```

am I missing something?

if you want all rows with value 'null' or empty string '' then :

```
SELECT * 
FROM KM_USER_MAST 
WHERE EXT_NO IS NULL OR EXT_NO = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the `NULL` values the way that you are using the function.  The expression `NULL = xxx` evaluates to false for all values of xxx.

You could, instead, write the `where` clause as:

```
SELECT *
FROM KM_USER_MAST
WHERE DBO.KM_GET_SRCH_PARAM(NULL, EXT_NO) = 1;
```

And define the function as:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[KM_GET_SRCH_PARAM](
                                @param          VARCHAR(8000),
                                @whereParam     VARCHAR(8000)
                            )
returns int
as    begin
    declare @returnValue int;
    IF @param IS NULL OR @param = ''
        SET @returnValue = 1;
    ELSE
        SET @returnValue = (case when @param = @WhereParam then 1 else 0 end);
    return @returnValue;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM KM_USER_MAST 
WHERE EXT_NO = COALESCE(NULL, EXT_NO)
```

or

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM KM_USER_MAST 
    WHERE EXT_NO = ISNULL(NULL, EXT_NO)
```

replace null with the parameter